# Return type of anonymous function

Tags: typescript

I've got an anonymous function like this:

```
static oneOf(options: any[], cb?: Function) ValidatorFn {
  ....
}
```

I want to specify that cb must return a boolean, but I'm a typescript newb and have no idea if I can (or even if it would make a difference to the parser if I did or not).

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function signature to specify the actual signature of your callback:

```
static oneOf(options: any[], cb?: () => boolean ): ValidatorFn { // cb takes no parameters returns a boolean
  ....
}
```

You can also specify callback arguments:

```
static oneOf(options: any[], cb?: (a: string) => boolean ): ValidatorFn { // cb takes a single string parameter returns a boolean
  ....
}
```